# Prove that $B ⊂ X$ is open if $B∩∂B = Ø$.

Tags: general-topology

[image]With $(X,τ)$ beeing a topological space.
The statement is pretty obvious. For a set B, if the topological boundary is not fully in the set, the set is considered open, per definition.
In our case, not a single element of the boundry is inside the set. $B∩∂B = Ø$.
Has someone an idea on how to approach this?

Comment: I'd start by writing out the definitions of $\partial B$ and "$B$ is open". Then it should be easy to relate these.

Comment: **Hint :** $$\emptyset = B \cap \partial B = B \cap \left( \overline{B} \setminus \mathrm{int}(B)\right)  = B \setminus \mathrm{int}(B)$$

Comment: Does $B$ without $  int(B)=∅$ imply that $B=int(B)$ and because of that $B$ has no boundry that is in $B$? That would explain why $B$ must be an open set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This becomes obvious if you write out the definitions. Consider  some point $x \in X$ and the balls $B(x,r)$ for all values of $r>0$. There are three possibilities.

1. Some $B(x,r)$ is contained in $B$
2. Some $B(x,r)$ is contained in $X/B$
3. Every $B(x,r)$ meets both $B$ and $X/B$

By considering whether $x \in B$ or $x \in X/B$ we can see exactly one of the above is true for each $x$. i.e for $x \in B$ either (1) or (2) is true and for $x \in X/B$ either (2) or (3) is true.

Now (1) is the definition of the interior of $B$. (2) is the boundary. (3) is the interior of $X/B$.

The rest is straightforward.